# Need to parameterized type's method to an implementation of a repository

Tags: c#

I have a Repository class:

```
public class Repository<T> where T : IMappable
{
     public virtual List<IMappable> Get()
     {
          return new DataProvider().Get(/* somehow use T's Map() method */);
     }
}

internal class DataProvider
{
     public delegate IMappable Mapper(Object dataSource);
     public List<IMappable> Get(Mapper mapper)
     {
          List<IMappable> mappables = new List<IMappable>();
          //Paraphrasing
          foreach(var ds in dataSource)
          {
              mappables.Add(mapper(ds));
          }
          return mappables;
     }
}

public interface IMappable
{
     IMappable Map(Object dataSource);
}
```

When I make a `Repository<TypeThatImplementsIMappable>` I want to pass it to use the generic type's Map method.  I cannot use reflection or the code DOM for performance reasons (I guess this is the cutoff for performance we are allowed to have).  How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `new` constraint to `T`:

```
public class Repository<T> where T : IMappable, new()
{
     public virtual List<IMappable> Get()
     {
          T mapper = new T();
          return new DataProvider().Get(mapper.Map);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, forgot entirely about that constraint :)